# Add zero values in chart

Tags: mysql

I built the following query:

```
SELECT GVA14.COD_ZONA, Sum(GVA12.IMPORTE) AS SumOfIMPORTE
FROM GVA14 LEFT JOIN GVA12 
  ON GVA14.COD_CLIENT = GVA12.COD_CLIENT
WHERE Month(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curdate())
AND Year(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Year(curdate())
GROUP BY GVA14.COD_ZONA;
```

But there are other values in the `COD_ZONA` that I want to display. These are there if I take the Month and Year filters away. Here is a SQL Fiddle for anyone intrested. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aae1/3

---

Edit 1#

I now have the following query:

```
SELECT GVA14.COD_ZONA, Coalesce(Sum(GVA12.IMPORTE), 0) AS SumOfIMPORTE
FROM GVA14 
LEFT JOIN GVA12 
  ON GVA14.COD_CLIENT = GVA12.COD_CLIENT
  AND Month(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curdate())
  AND Year(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Year(curdate())
GROUP BY GVA14.COD_ZONA;
```

But when I try and execute it, it takes 110 secs aprox and the program I need it for times out before that. I've created an index on the suggestion of @Bluefeet and called it Zones and included the GVA14.COD_ZONA in it.

What do I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this by adding 4 indexes (don't know if that's too many!) on the tables. It worked...

Answer (score 2):

Move the filters on the `WHERE` clause to the `JOIN` condition. If you leave the filters on the `WHERE` clause them the query acts like an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT GVA14.COD_ZONA, Coalesce(Sum(GVA12.IMPORTE), 0) AS SumOfIMPORTE
FROM GVA14 
LEFT JOIN GVA12 
  ON GVA14.COD_CLIENT = GVA12.COD_CLIENT
  AND Month(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curdate())
  AND Year(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Year(curdate())
GROUP BY GVA14.COD_ZONA;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aae1/5)

Result:

```
| COD_ZONA | SUMOFIMPORTE |
---------------------------
|       01 |         3000 |
|       02 |         1000 |
|       03 |            0 |
```

Comment: The only problem now is that it take a long time to excute, sometimes resulting in a timeout. Could this be because of a large table?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table?

Comment: In Navicat it took 110 seconds to excuted. Is that long or not?

Comment: I don't think that there are any indexes.

Comment: I've added an index now, what next?

Comment: Adding indexes on all the columns of the query fixed the slow query time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT GVA14.COD_ZONA
         , COALESCE(Sum(GVA12.IMPORTE),0) AS SumOfIMPORTE
      FROM GVA14 
      LEFT 
      JOIN GVA12 
        ON GVA14.COD_CLIENT = GVA12.COD_CLIENT
       AND Month(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Month(curdate())
       AND Year(GVA12.FECHA_EMIS)=Year(curdate())
     GROUP 
        BY GVA14.COD_ZONA;
```